# Design pattern - filtered view of a data type that's composed inside another class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm working with a `data_type` but my project requires that the `data_type` conform to certain specifications so I have a class `wrapper` that includes a `data_type` within it.

```
class wrapper {
private:
    wrapper();
    
public:
    ~wrapper();

    static wrapper * create() {...}

    void member_one(...) {
        // Does stuff to m_ to enforce particular specification
        do_stuff(m_);
    }

    ...

    void member_ten(...) {
        // Does stuff to m_ to enforce particular specification
        do_more_stuff(m_);
    }

protected:
    // Do not expose, since we don't want users to add arbitrary stuff that does not conform to spec
    data_type m_;
};
```

Now, I am working with a third-party library that provides a view adapter to provide a filtered view of `data_type`.  It takes a `data_type` and provides a `filtered_data_type` object.

Keeping in the spirit of my design above, I would like to make a `filtered_wrapper` that inherits from `wrapper`.  It can have a `filtered_data_type` as its data member, which is constructed using the base class' `data_type`.

Problem solved, except that the functions `member_one()`...`member_ten()` can act equally on `filtered_data_type` as they do on `data_type`, and I want users of `filtered_wrapper` to be able to do this (a) without having to override all of the functions in `filtered_wrapper` to do the same thing but on a different data member and (b) while templates are a good solution to this, they expose the data_type and its own templated construction which I am trying to hide from the user, so I want to avoid templates unless there's another template pattern that addresses this.

**Is there a design pattern to achieve what I am trying to do?**

UPDATE 7/5:

`filtered_data_type` is not derived from `data_type`.  Those data types and associated `do_stuff` functions are implemented as generics, meaning `do_stuff` (referenced above) are in the library namespace, not member methods, and work on `data_type` and `filtered_data_type`; they are implemented using templates.  Further, instantiation of a `filtered_data_type` requires a reference to an underlying `data_type` and it is not default-constructible. This proves to be an added consideration/complication...

So I have a solution that factors out the common functionality (e.g., `member_one()`) so that it can be re-used in the different wrapper classes and ideally, their potential future subclasses too.

I have tested this out, and there are some issues that I don't understand.  I wish to understand the drawbacks of the design so that I don't corner myself later.

In this solution, I use a variant of CRTP to provide common functionality (e.g., `member_one()`) to all derived classes.

```
class wrapper_base {
public:
    wrapper_base() = default;
    ~wrapper_base() = default;

// This provides the functionality common to both 
// the wrappers for `filtered_data_type` and `data_type`
template < class Derived, class Base, class DataType >
class wrapper_interface : Base {
public:
    virtual ~wrapper_interface() = default;
    void member_one(...) {
        do_stuff( data() );
    }
protected:
    wrapper_interface() = default;

private:
    const Derived * derived() const {
        return static_cast<const Derived *>(this);
    }

    Derived * derived() {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this);
    }

    const DataType & data() const {
        return derived()->data_();
    }
  
    DataType & data() {
        return derived()->data_();
    }
} // wrapper_interface
```

Now, I can define the `wrapper` and `filtered_wrapper` as follows, e.g.:

```
class wrapper : public wrapper_interface<wrapper,wrapper_base,data_type> {
public:
    ...
    const data_type & data() const {
       return m_;

    data_type & data() {
       return m_;
    }
private:
    data_type m_;
}
```

and

```
class filtered_wrapper : public wrapper_interface<wrapper,wrapper_base,filtered_data_type> {
public:
    // filtered_data_type not default constructible
    filtered_wrapper(param x)
    :m_(x)
    ...
    const filtered_data_type & data() const {
       return m_;

    filtered_data_type & data() {
       return m_;
    }
private:
    // not default constructible
    filtered_data_type m_;
}
```

This works great, in that I can create a `wrapper` or `filtered_wrapper` instance, and call the methods common to both implemented in the `wrapper_interface` class (e.g., `member_one`).

Now, let's say that I decide that I need multiple `filtered_wrapper` that add successive features (`special_filtered_wrapper`). I have two choices:

1. Subclass `filtered_wrapper` as you normally would
2. Use the CRTP to "shift" the derive/base template parameters down a notch.

For the second approach, the definition of `special_filtered_wrapper` would look like:

```
class special_filtered_wrapper: public wrapper_interface<special_filtered_wrapper,filtered_wrapper,filtered_data_type>
```

There is one main problem with this - `filtered_data_type` is not default constructible, and now I have indirect inheritance (`special_filtered_wrapper` does not inherit directly from `filtered_wrapper`) and hence cannot call the base class constructor with parameter `x` to initialize `filtered_data_type`).

Now, using approach (1), I have a compile-time error which I do not understand.  Basically, if I do:

```
special_filtered_wrapper a;
a.member_one()
```

I get the following error:

```
no matching function call to do_stuff(filtered_data_type &)
```

This error does not occur for `filtered_wrapper` or `wrapper`, so it seems to stem from the fact that there's an extra subclass. The `do_stuff` function does in fact expect a `filtered_data_type &` (or `const filtered_data_Type &`), and the fact that the compiler has made substitutions to get to that point tells me there are no template issues...

**Question 1:** Is there a viable alternative to the CRTP-based approach, or this whole approach for that matter?

**Question 2:** Why the compiler error?

Comment: check CRTP, maybe that could help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)

Comment: Do you know on the create call, that Wrapper is going to have filtered data or "base" data?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX The desired use case is such that you always have "base" data (you create that object first), then you can attach a filtered view adapter (filtered_wrapper) to an existing wrapper.  So in each create() call the user should know what they desire - base or filtered.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia CRTP definitely helps (no need to re-define all functions in derived, if base classes uses templated type) - however when creating base class objects is the templated type not exposed/supplied by user?  I guess you could set a default type...hmm

Comment: Is filtered_data_type going to be a derived class of data_type? If so, why do you need another wrapper? Cannot the existing wrapper take a (smart) pointer of data_type to avoid slicing and the code will be unchanged.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi If I understand you correctly, that would require the user to supply data_type or filtered_data_type as appropriate. The construction and templated parameters involved in generating those data types is to be hidden from the user, as I've described.

Comment: I'm thinking CRTP with 3 classes is the solution - an abstract base class, then 2 (non-templated) classes...for each to accommodate data_type and filtered_data_type.

Comment: @user3814483 not really, you don't show the code that construct the wrapper, but you can easily provide a factory that return the smart pointer to hide the selection of the object from the user. CRTP and dynamic polymorphism achieve the same result with different pro/cons balance.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi So in your proposal you have 2 factory methods, one for data_type and one for filtered_data_type, and the class is templated... correct? I will need to check whether filtered_data_type is derived from data_type; they are third-party.

Comment: This is the idea, no template pure dynamic polymorphism: struct D { ... }; struct F : D { ... }; struct W { D* data; ... static W* create(...) };  Assumption filtered "is a" data_type. Used struct and raw pointer just to squeeze this in the comment. CRTP is not requiring D and F to have "is a" relationship but just to share the same interface (and just the subset that you are going to use), so I guess it is more flexible